# Redactor clips plugin does not paste the exact html

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, cakephp, redactor

I was trying to use the **clips plugin** in Redactor.

My needs is: create some templates using the Twitter Bootstrap syntax/classes.

---

I create this clip:

```
<li>
  <a href="#" class="redactor_clip_link">Template 2 Colunas</a>

  <div class="redactor_clip" style="display: none;">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="span4">
        <h2>Digite o titulo aqui</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsa, sequi ea rerum minima dolor ratione cumque vero repellendus ipsam! Porro, quasi repellat modi. Doloremque, quis, error neque molestias fugit natus modi ducimus? Error, tenetur, rerum debitis ipsa aspernatur sed sequi.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="span5">
        <h2>Digite o titulo aqui</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsa, sequi ea rerum minima dolor ratione cumque vero repellendus ipsam! Porro, quasi repellat modi. Doloremque, quis, error neque molestias fugit natus modi ducimus? Error, tenetur, rerum debitis ipsa aspernatur sed sequi.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</li>
```

But when the plugin tries to paste the code... the result is:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="span4">
        <h2>Digite o titulo aqui</h2>
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsa, sequi ea rerum minima dolor ratione cumque vero repellendus ipsam! Porro, quasi repellat modi. Doloremque, quis, error neque molestias fugit natus modi ducimus? Error, tenetur, rerum debitis ipsa aspernatur sed sequi.
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="span5">
        <h2>Digite o titulo aqui</h2>
    </div>
</div>
<p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsa, sequi ea rerum minima dolor ratione cumque vero repellendus ipsam! Porro, quasi repellat modi. Doloremque, quis, error neque molestias fugit natus modi ducimus? Error, tenetur, rerum debitis ipsa aspernatur sed sequi.
</p>
```

As you can see, after the `</h2>` clips plugin closes, all divs above and then put the `

'.

Why?

---

### Clips function

```
  insertClip: function(html)
  {
    this.selectionRestore();
    this.insertHtml($.trim(html));
    // this.insertHtmlAdvanced($.trim(html)); // doesn't work
    this.modalClose();
  }
```

---

### Redactor config

```
  $('#PageDescription').redactor({
    minHeight: 300,
    plugins: ['clips'],
    convertDivs: false,
    lang: 'pt_br',
    deniedTags: ['h1'],
    buttons: ['html', '|', 'formatting', '|', 'bold', 'italic', 'deleted', '|', 'unorderedlist', 'orderedlist', 'outdent', 'indent', '|', 'image', 'video', 'file', 'table', 'link', '|', '|', 'alignment', '|', 'horizontalrule'],
    imageUpload: '/admin/pages/upload_image',
    fileUpload: '/scripts/file_upload.php',
    keyupCallback: function (obj, event) {
      var max = $('#PageDescription').prop('maxlength');
      if (typeof max !== "undefined" && max > 0) {
        var current = obj.currentTarget.innerText.length;
        var $box = $('#PageDescription').parent(".redactor_box");
        var $redactor_indicator = $(".redactor_indicator", $box);
        if ($redactor_indicator.size() === 0) {
          $box.append($("<div class='redactor_indicator'><span class='current'>" + (current - 3) + "</span> of <span class='max'>" + max + "</span> caracteres restantes</div>"));
        } else {
          $(".current", $redactor_indicator).text(current - 3);
          $(".max", $redactor_indicator).text(max);
        }
        if (current >= max) {
          $box.css("border", "1px solid #ff0000");
          $redactor_indicator.css("color", "#ff0000");
        } else {
          $box.css("border", "1px solid #DDDDDD");
          $redactor_indicator.css("color", "#000000");
        }
      }
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the `insertHtml()` API function.

When I use the `set()` function, everythings works.

```
  insertClip: function(html)
  {
    this.selectionRestore();
    this.set($.trim(html)); // <---- change insertHtml() to set()
    this.modalClose();
  }
```